# How to override a SASS/SCSS function with new module structure?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have a requirement to override/overwrite the existing sass/scss function from an npm component library. I am eventually loading my custom scss file at the end. However, the overridden function is never invoked.

Note: The library uses the `@use` approach to import scss files.

```
@use '../core/theming/theming';

@mixin _checked-color($palette, $thumb-checked-hue) {
  &.mat-checked {
    .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
      // Here `theming.get-color-from-palette()` is getting invoked
      // from the library instead of overridden by me.
      background-color: theming.get-color-from-palette($palette, $thumb-checked-hue);
    }
  }
```

Could someone share any reference or lead to overriding an existing scss function?